# How does Spatial Dropout work in the inference compared to Dropout?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, spatial, dropout

I would like to deploy a trained Keras model on a microcontroller. However, there is no support for Spatial Dropout layer. I thought about removing the layer from the graph similarly to the Dropout layer. However I didn't find any indication on how the Spatial Dropout works in inference.

I have tried to look into the documentations or similar problem but couldn't find any indication about it.

Comment: Check call arguments: https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/spatial_dropout1d/

Comment: @Frightera In the dropout layer, they also say the same thing, i.e, "training mode (adding dropout) or in inference mode (doing nothing)". That is because Inputs not set to 0 are scaled up by 1/(1 - rate) such that the sum over all inputs is unchanged. In the Spatial dropout there's no indication about this.

Comment: Documentation clearly states that: *in inference mode (doing nothing)*